# How to fix spaceship interaction with the boundaries and more?

Tags: c++, sfml

```
#pragma once
#include "Globals.h"
#include "ResourceManager.h"
#include "ResourceIdentifier.h"
#include "Entity.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Shooter : public Entity{

private:
    bool m_isClicked;
    bool m_ableToMove;
    float m_lastAngle;
    bool m_mouseInBounds;
    sf::Vector2i m_targetPos;

public:
    Shooter();
    void initialize(const TextureManager&);
    void moveShip(float dt);
    void angleShipToMouse(const sf::Vector2i&);
    void handleInput(const sf::Event&, const sf::Vector2i&);
    void update(const sf::Vector2i&, float);
    void adjustingTarget();
};


#include "SpaceShooter.h"

Shooter::Shooter() : m_ableToMove(false), m_isClicked(false), m_lastAngle(0)
{
}

void Shooter::initialize(const TextureManager& text)
{
    m_speed = sf::Vector2i(500, 500);
    this->m_sprite.setTexture(text.get(TextureID::Shooter));
    this->m_sprite.setOrigin(m_sprite.getGlobalBounds().width / 2.0f, m_sprite.getGlobalBounds().height / 2.0f);
    this->m_sprite.setPosition(Globals::_windowWidth / 2.0f, Globals::_windowHeight / 2.0f); //start 50 units out
}

void Shooter::moveShip(float dt) {

    if (m_isClicked && !m_ableToMove) {
        m_ableToMove = true;
        m_isClicked = false;   
    }

    if (m_ableToMove) {
        adjustingTarget();
        sf::Vector2f shipComponentDistances(abs(m_targetPos.x - getX()), abs(m_targetPos.y - getY()));
        sf::Vector2f shipVelocity(cos(m_angle * Globals::deg2rad) * dt * m_speed.x,
        sin(m_angle*Globals::deg2rad) * dt * m_speed.y);

        float targetDistance = sqrt(pow(shipComponentDistances.x, 2) + pow(shipComponentDistances.y, 2));
        float distanceToTravel = sqrt(pow(shipVelocity.x, 2) + pow(shipVelocity.y, 2));

        if (targetDistance > distanceToTravel) {
            this->m_sprite.move(shipVelocity);
            m_lastAngle = m_angle;
    //  std::cout << distance << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            this->m_sprite.setPosition(m_targetPos.x - 0.01, m_targetPos.y - 0.01);
            std::cout << m_lastAngle << std::endl;
            this->m_sprite.setRotation(m_lastAngle);
            std::cout << this->m_sprite.getRotation() << std::endl;
            m_ableToMove = false;
            m_isClicked = false;
        }
    }
}

void Shooter::angleShipToMouse(const sf::Vector2i& mousePosition) {

    //position of mouse relative to ship in 0 rotation reference frame(absolute)
    sf::Vector2f mouseRelativeShip(mousePosition.x - getX(), mousePosition.y - getY());


    float rotation = atan2(mouseRelativeShip.y, mouseRelativeShip.x)*Globals::rad2deg; //atan2 produces negative angles if vector is in QUADS 1&2, positive in QUADS 3&4

    this->m_sprite.setRotation(rotation);

    m_angle = this->m_sprite.getRotation();
}

void Shooter::handleInput(const sf::Event& event, const sf::Vector2i& mousePos) {
    if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left) {  
        if (!m_ableToMove && !m_isClicked) {
            m_isClicked = true;
            m_targetPos = mousePos;
        }
    }
}

void Shooter::update(const sf::Vector2i& mousePosition, float dt) {
    angleShipToMouse(mousePosition);
    moveShip(dt);
}

void Shooter::adjustingTarget()
{
    if (m_targetPos.x < spriteWidth() / 2.0f) {
        m_targetPos.x = spriteWidth() / 2.0f;
    }
    else if (m_targetPos.x > Globals::_windowWidth - spriteWidth() / 2.0f) {
        m_targetPos.x = Globals::_windowWidth - spriteWidth() / 2.0f;
    }
    else if(m_targetPos.y < spriteHeight() / 2.0f){
        m_targetPos.y = spriteHeight() / 2.0f;
    }
    else if (m_targetPos.y > Globals::_windowHeight - spriteHeight() / 2.0f) {
        m_targetPos.y = Globals::_windowHeight - spriteHeight() / 2.0f;
    }
}
```

The problems with my spaceship are:
1. despite not allowing for changing of targetPos when !moving, clicking while its moving to a different location will cause it to redirect the ship. Holding down the ship causes it to follow the mouse cursor.

2. once ship reaches the targetPosition, the rotation of the ship gets set to 0, im trying to make it retain the rotation of the angle just prior to it reaching its destination (e.g. distance to targetPos is 0).
3. When it reaches the boundaries sometimes it can go through it despite me adjusting the targetPosition if the mouse is too far into a deadzone the ship cannot enter.